# How do I add a static CollectionView cell after my dynamic CollectionView cells? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Hey I'm trying to add a static collection view cell after my dynamic collection view cells. For example in my screenshot, under the "Study Grind Edition" collectionview, Philz Coffee is the first cell but I hope to add another cell next to it that is static that would say "Rate more cafes for more selection!" or something along those lines. Likewise, in the "Thanks a Brunch" section, if there is no Cafe cell, it would only display the "Rate more cafes for more selection!" cell as the first cell. Would I add a second section for that? Thank you so much!

[image]

Comment: Have you looked into adding a footerview to that collection view?  You could register a footer view in that section and display it if some condition is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create another cellClass (or Another cell in you storyboard) and just add it programmaticaly in your collectionView after the last element.

Regards